# RestartManager cannot shutdown program that uses ApplicationContext

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application that is created with:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new ApplicationMenuContext());
```

where ApplicationMenuContext is a class that inherits ApplicationContext.

```
public class ApplicationMenuContext : ApplicationContext
{
}
```

When the user shuts down the appication this is what happens:

```
ExitThread();
```

Which in turn calls the overrided:

```
protected override void ExitThreadCore()
{
    base.ExitThreadCore();
}
```

Which also calls the dispose:

```
protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
{
    if( disposing && components != null) { components.Dispose(); }
}
```

Shutting down the app works great. User hits the exitContextMenu, and the app properly shuts down gracefully. However, when the Windows Installer attempts to shutdown the app, None of these functions get hit! So obviously I'm not capturing something, but I am totally at a loss. What should I be capturing from RestartManager so that I can properly call ExitThread?